# List all User Entitlements for ADO

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, azure-devops-rest-api

Are you looking for the List User Entitlements or Get User Entitlements APIs that were available in previous versions of the MS Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

It is now called Search Entitlements and can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/search%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).